# Excel: Moving Specific Text to Another Row / Column

Tags: excel, format, vba

Good afternoon,

I am having some difficulty separating data that is in one column. I have tons of rows, but the person that uploaded the data merged everything into one column. The entire column has education, age, male, female, and blood type. I want to take the patients attributes and put them into five columns. Is there a way I can move data into five columns without using "text to columns" in "data" in Excel?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
 EducationAge MaleFemale Bloodtype 
 MiddleAlabama21 10 ABpos
 WestGov22 01 Bneg
 VirginaTech25 01 ABpos
```

Comment: **Are all ages greater than 9 ??**

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8 is exactly what you need, you should be able to programmatically use the search function to find and split your string by blank space

Comment: All ages are above 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999)),LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999)))-2)
```

in **C1** enter:

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999)),2)
```

In **D1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999))
```

and in **E1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:C)*999-998,999))
```

[image]

This will work if the ages are **2** digits *(greater than 9 and less than 100)*

Also note that I have left the male/female field as a single **2** digit field.

Answer (score 2):

For the vba, and this is dependent on the age always being two digits.

```
Sub splitStr()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim spltStr() As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet4")
    With ws
        For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            spltStr = split(Trim(rng))
            rng.Offset(, 1) = Left(spltStr(0), Len(spltStr(0)) - 2)
            rng.Offset(, 2) = --Right(spltStr(0), 2)
            rng.Offset(, 3) = --Left(spltStr(1), 1)
            rng.Offset(, 4) = --Right(spltStr(1), 1)
            rng.Offset(, 5) = spltStr(2)
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

This will not do the headers.  Those were hand typed.